# Autodesk AR/VR Toolkit Request not working in Unity3d WEBGL?

Tags: unity-game-engine, autodesk-forge, autodesk-arvr

i get an error in Unity3d WEBGL when i want to request this point:
GET /modelderivative/v2/arkit/{urn}/scenes/{scene_id}

No troubles accessing this point via https://reqbin.com/
No troubles accessing this point in the Unity-Editor.

WEBGL Error: Access-Control-Allow-Origin    Missing Header

Is Autodesk blocking Unity WEBGL?
I want to make a custom web-viewer with Unity3d.

Greets

Comment: Its not blocking webgl. Its cors. It blocks all manner of crap.

Comment: [CORS](https://portswigger.net/web-security/cors)

Comment: I get no error with a PHP/Curl Request, i will send it to Unity-WEBGL this way

Answer (score 1):

As the guys already said in the comments, this is a security measure imposed by [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Btw. here's a shameless plug: I'm the author of the [forge-convert-utils](https://github.com/petrbroz/forge-convert-utils) library that can be used to convert Forge models into [glTF 2.0](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/tree/master/specification/2.0). With it you could host the glTF assets anywhere you want (and have the server use any CORS headers that are needed), and you can load them into your Unity app using any of the glTF loaders such as [glTFast](https://github.com/atteneder/glTFast) or [UnityGLTF](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/UnityGLTF).